# Advantage of using "--syn" for matching new TCP connections

Tags: iptables, tcp

I have seen a similar technique used in several `iptables` examples for matching new connections:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j SSH
```

As seen above, TCP connections are checked against TCP flags(SYN has to be 1 and RST, ACK and FIN 0) by `tcp` module besides `--ctstate NEW` of `conntrack` module. Does it provide any advantage over this:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j SSH
```

My assumption is that it does because match modules are evaluated in the order they are specified in the rule and without `--syn`, **all** the TCP packets to port 443 would be passed from `tcp` module to `conntrack` module. In other words, `--syn` should provide this fail-fast paradigm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In other words, `--syn` should provide this fail-fast paradigm.

That’s pretty much it. In practice, it’s the extension mechanism which is short-circuiting; [the manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/iptables.8.html#OPTIONS) says

> Matches are
>                 evaluated first to last as specified on the command line and
>                 work in short-circuit fashion, i.e. if one extension yields
>                 false, evaluation will stop.

In the above case, the rule uses two extensions: the `tcp` extension, which processes `--dport` and `--syn`, followed by the `conntrack` extension, which processes `--ctstate`. If the `tcp` extension fails to match, the `conntrack` extension will be skipped entirely.