# Advantage of using “--ctstate NEW” in addition to "--sync" for matching new TCP connections

Tags: iptables

In iptables context, to match a new TCP connection, one can use:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

However, is `--ctstate NEW` necessary provided that the `--syn` flag is already there? In other words, aren't `--syn` packets always NEW by definition and, thus, the state checking is redundant or is there any benefit in doing it? Can `--syn` packets be not NEW?

I've read a lot of examples and, sometimes, the state checking is dropped but in other (most) texts it's still present. Also, I found these related questions but cannot figure out a precise answer to my specific question:

[Advantage of using "--syn" for matching new TCP connections](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/432625/424675)

https://serverfault.com/q/338553

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I've always found both `--syn` and `--ctstate NEW` to be redundant because I have `-m state --state INVALID -j DROP` as the first rule for all the relevant chains.

The thinking is maybe you want to be a purist and follow the TCP/IP stack to the letter which means only a new connection must be `--syn`, i.e. you cannot send a SYN packet within an already established connection because to terminate it you must use `FIN`.